# SSH connection using another port in OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, port

I want to connect through the terminal in OS X to my Linux server with SSH - But how do i connect if i changed the SSH port to, lets say, 5000 instead os 22?

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to consult the [man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh.1.html).

Comment: if i knew of the man pages i would have looked it up. Didn't come up as a hit in my Google search..

Comment: The man pages are an excellent resource, and a staple of using a Unix-like system. You should ensure they're installed on your system. Then just type `man ssh`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The man pages on mac are a bit of a mess, as witness the fact that ssh(1) clearly documents the ip:port syntax -- which doesn't work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the command line option `-p` for `ssh`:

```
ssh -p 5000 host
```